Create concentric scaled rings with individual noise translation to each instance
I am attempting to create the following outcome using a generated Curve Circle in geo nodes.

What I want to do:

Duplicate the Curve Circle a few times.
Then scale them down concentrically
Be able to adjust the Curve Circle instances to be equally spaced to randomly spaced
Then be able to give each generated Curve Circle its own noise deformation.


Hope you can educate and share some knowledge with me.
TX


Duplicates with noise offset
It's actually quite easy to achieve. With the Duplicate Elements node you are using, you get an index output that you can use to offset the noise texture differently for each duplicate. Here is the node setup for the noise :

In the order of the node tree :

Multiply the Duplicate Index by some factor. If you feel the noise isn't spread out enough, increase it.
Use it as Z input of a 3D vector.
Offset the position with it
Compute Noise Texture
Noise textures are going from 0 to 1, let's remap it from -1 to 1 (i.e. center offset).
Decrease amplitude of noise.

If it helps you understand, I've also added another example (the one in the center). The result is the same, but I've decomposed each step more clearly : move rings up > get noise > move rings down.
Finally, the full node tree and the blend file :

Blend file


Thank you so much, your explanation was a great help!
